# I can't put a section with background above Google Maps iframe

Tags: html, css

I've got an issue, while trying to create an overlay above google maps iframe. The background-color isn't aplying in CSS. Are there any restrictions from Google and what's a proper solution to this?

```css
.ellenonmap {
    background-color:white!important;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d100621.22936695188!2d23.66829933952863!3d37.990816432734675!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x14a1bd1f067043f1%3A0x2736354576668ddd!2zzpHOuM6uzr3OsQ!5e0!3m2!1sel!2sgr!4v1652863273042!5m2!1sel!2sgr" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
<section class="ellenonmap">
  <h1>Επικοινωνία</h1><br>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i><h4>Το κατάστημά μας:</h4><br>
   <h4><i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>Το κατάστημά μας:</h4><br>
</section>
```

Comment: If you inspect the page, you will see that the section has white background, but it is positioned under the map. Maybe you just want to specify a position like `position: relative`

Comment: That was the solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.ellenonmap`. Then you can adjust the style as you wish.